# Moving Exact Data

Tags: vba, excel

Good Morning,

I am looking to build a macro to move data between 2 Sheets

In the first sheet, I have data from my manufacture which I called that sheet "original"

In my second Sheet, I called "Finished".

I want to move Data from Original to Finished

In my Original sheet, those headers are not aligned nor are they named the same as in my finished sheet.

in My original sheet, I have a column D which has 3 types of products "Parent, Product Variant, and Standard" so depending on which type of product that data has to be moved into different cells.

So I may need to move original A1 to finished H1 because the match is standard
But if the Match is Parent I may need to move original A1 to C1
or if the match is Product Variation I might need to move A1 to I1

So I am trying to simplify this process

I also may have to merge cells depending on if it is Standard, Parent or Product Variant so I might have data in A1, F1 and AA 1 that have to merged together with a "," or "/" in between

Thanks for any help on pointing me in the right direction for the macro that can help me sort this

```
Sub Kroll()

Dim i As Long

    lastrow lastrow = Sheets("Original").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    Sheets("Standard").Range("A2:I999999").ClearContents

    For i = 2 To lastrow

        If Sheets("original").Cells(i, "D").Value = "Parent Product" Then
            Sheets("original").Cells(i, "E").EntireRow.Copy _
                        Destination:=Sheets("Standard").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? What happened?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [mcve]. *"having issues"* is useless as a problem statement.

Comment: Tried that but we are having issues moving the data

Comment: @TimFugate instead of throwing code in a comment, put it in your original question, properly formatted, then people may be able to see what might be happening...

Comment: @SolarMike I have been trying to add the text in comment but it keeps wrapping the text like above. how do you fix it???

Comment: @TimFugate the comment box is for comments - not code, so you cannot format code in a comment box... Put it in your original question using the code button...

Comment: @SolarMike I put it up there but it keeps changing it from how long the string is wrote in the original

Comment: @storax I seen where you made the edits. But that code only moved the entire line. We don't know what to add in there to move specific cells to other specific cells in both workbooks

Comment: I just edited your post in order to make it more readable for the audience. I did  not fix or change any code

Comment: Oh ok, I have been on all day trying to find a code that may work and was wondering if it is atall possible to maybe add to the code to make it work

Answer (score 0):

I've provided some code which may help you moving some data assuming column D is something like in  the picture provided. For the merging problem you have to provide some more detailed explanation and example on what you want being merged.

[Picture assumed Column D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3s1d.png)

```
Option Explicit


Sub Moving_Exact_Data()

'''https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51348750/moving-exact-data'''
Dim originalSheet As Worksheet
Dim finishedSheet As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim productRange As Range
Dim i As Integer

'Assuming original sheet is Sheet1
Set originalSheet = Sheet1

'Assuming finished sheet is Sheet2
Set finishedSheet = Sheet2

lastRow = originalSheet.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastRow
    With originalSheet
        If .Cells(i, 4) = "Parent" Then
            finishedSheet.Cells(i, 3) = .Cells(i, 4)
        ElseIf .Cells(i, 4) = "Product Variant" Then
            finishedSheet.Cells(i, 9) = .Cells(i, 4)
        ElseIf .Cells(i, 4) = "Standard" Then
            finishedSheet.Cells(i, 8) = .Cells(i, 4)
        Else
            MsgBox ("no match")
        End If
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```